# ratingbar does not filled the float value coming from JSON android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, rating, ratingbar

the thing is if rating is 3.5 then ratingbar fills upto 3 star ...it doesnt filled half of the fourth star....

I dont know where im going wrong  Need help thanks:Following is my code

rating:

```
    <RatingBar
        android:numStars="5"
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="#7F7F7F"
        android:progressTint="#FFBA00"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
      />
```

here is my adapter:-not posting full code just an important part

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.productname.text = Tablelist.get(position).name
    holder.producername.text = Tablelist.get(position).producer

    holder.productprice.text = Tablelist.get(position).cost.toString()

    Glide.with(context).load(Tablelist.get(position).product_images)
        .into(holder.image)
    holder.rate.setRating(Tablelist.get(position).rating);
 //   holder.rate.setStepSize(Tablelist.get(position).rating);// to show to stars


    holder.itemView!!.setOnClickListener {


        val context:Context=holder.itemView.context
        val i=Intent(context,
            Product_details::class.java)
        i.putExtra("id",Tablelist.get(position).id.toString())
      Log.e("checkid",Tablelist.get(position).id.toString())
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}

fun setMovieListItems(movieList: List<Table_data>){
    this.Tablelist = movieList;
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

    val productname: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.title)
    val producername: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.title1)
    val productprice: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.title2)
    val rate: RatingBar=itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar)

    val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.image)

}
```

here is my Tablelist:

```
data class Table_data (

@SerializedName("id") val id : Int,
@SerializedName("product_category_id") val product_category_id : Int,
@SerializedName("name") val name : String,
@SerializedName("producer") val producer : String,
@SerializedName("description") val description : String,
@SerializedName("cost") val cost : Int,
@SerializedName("rating") val rating : Float=0.0f,
@SerializedName("view_count") val view_count : Int,
@SerializedName("created") val created : String,
@SerializedName("modified") val modified : String,
@SerializedName("product_images") val product_images : String
)
```

Comment: Try setting `android:stepSize="0.5"` in the layout xml.

Comment: @shafayathossain still doesnt worked filling only 3 star for 3.5

Comment: Please give updated code after adding `android:stepSize="0.5"`.

Comment: Did you check the value of `Tablelist.get(position).rating`?

Comment: @shafayathossain it gives like this `E/checkratevalue: 2.0 E/checkratevalue: 3.0 ,E/checkratevalue: 4.0` for this -->        Log.e("checkratevalue",Tablelist.get(position).rating.toString())

Comment: @shafayathossain everything is `.0` only not having `0.5`.....but in postman rating values are 3.5,4.5 like this

Comment: Then you have solve that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but here problem might be with the float conversion from json adapter. what you can do is get the field as String, so the value is not lost at the time of conversion.

```
@SerializedName("rating") val rating : String,
```

now in your adapter try to convert this to float.

```
 holder.rate.setRating(Tablelist.get(position).rating.toFloat())
```

can you try this one.

Comment: previously it was giving like this on log E/checkratevalue: 1.0 ...now after your method it gives like this E/checkratevalue: 1

Comment: can you print the raw value from string

Comment: can you print your api server response from logcat do you have added any interceptors

Comment: if rating string has 3.5 as value then toFloat() on it should give 3.5 , else you are receiving something else or there is some conversion happening in between. add debug point and see the received value from server and while adding to adapter

Comment: i got it ..it is happening in some conversion happening in between. add debug point and see the received value ...thanks ..

Comment: hey need help in here  --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224711/kotlin-typecastexception-null-cannot-be-cast-to-non-null-type-kotlin-collection