# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, null, mutable

please dont marked as duplicate , as the question is slightly different --->  null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.**MutableList**

**Scenerios**:-

i have been performing delete cart using retrofit..

1. if atleast one item is present ,it displays in recyclerview

2.if cart is empty ,it crashes with a above error

here is my adapter code:-

```
class CartAdapter(context: Context, dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>) :
RecyclerSwipeAdapter<CartAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() { //added RecyclerSwipeAdapter and override
 private   var dataList: MutableList<DataCart>
private val context: Context
 lateinit var  dialog:ProgressDialog
var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null


inner class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val mView: View
   val swipelayout:SwipeLayout
    val productiamge: ImageView
    val productname: TextView
    val productcategory: TextView
    val productprice: TextView
    val quantity:TextView
    val tvDelete:TextView
    init {
        mView = itemView
    productiamge= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagecart)
       productname= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagenamecart)
        productcategory= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagecategory)
     productprice =mView.findViewById(R.id.price)
        quantity=mView.findViewById(R.id.quantity)
        swipelayout=mView.findViewById(R.id.swipe)
        tvDelete=mView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete)
    }

}

      override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addtocart_item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position: Int): Int {
    return R.id.swipe;

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val  progressDialog :ProgressDialog= ProgressDialog(context);

    holder.productname.text = dataList.get(position).product.name ?: null
    holder.productcategory.text = "(" +dataList.get(position).product.product_category +")"

    holder.productprice.text = dataList.get(position).product.cost.toString()

    Glide.with(context).load(dataList.get(position).product.product_images)
        .into(holder.productiamge)
    holder.quantity.text=dataList.get(position).quantity.toString()

    holder.swipelayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut)
    Log.e("checkidd",dataList.get(position).product.id.toString())
    // Drag From Right

    // Drag From Right
    holder.swipelayout.addDrag(
        SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right,
        holder.swipelayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper)
    )
    val id =dataList.get(position).product?.id

        holder.swipelayout.addSwipeListener(object : SwipeListener {
        override fun onClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {            }

        override fun onUpdate(layout: SwipeLayout, leftOffset: Int, topOffset: Int) {
            //you are swiping.
        }

        override fun onStartOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
        override fun onOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {
        }

        override fun onStartClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
        override fun onHandRelease(
            layout: SwipeLayout,
            xvel: Float,
            yvel: Float
        ) {
        }
    })
    holder.swipelayout.getSurfaceView()
        .setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        })

   holder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    view ->

    val token :String = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).user.access_token.toString()
RetrofitClient.instancecart.deletecart(token,id!!)
    .enqueue(object : Callback<DeleteResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeleteResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<DeleteResponse>,
            response: Response<DeleteResponse>
        ) {
            var res = response

            if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    res.body()?.message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                progress()
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(holder.swipelayout)
                notifyItemChanged(position)
                notifyItemRemoved(position)
                dataList?.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dataList?.size!!)
                mItemManger.closeAllItems()
                progressDialog.show()
            }
            else{
                try {
                    val jObjError =
                        JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                }
            }
        }
    })
mItemManger.bindView(holder.itemView, position)
     })
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
}
fun progress()
{
    progressDialog?.dismiss()
    val intent =
        Intent(context.applicationContext, AddToCart::class.java)
    intent.flags =
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
    context.applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
}

    init {
    this.context = context
    this.dataList = dataList 
   }}
```

here is my activity:

```
   class AddToCart:AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.add_to_cart)
   val totalamount:TextView=findViewById(R.id.totalamount)
    val token: String =
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
            applicationContext
        ).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instancecart.listcart(token).enqueue( object :
        Callback<CartResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CartResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"falied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<CartResponse>,
            response: Response<CartResponse>
        ) {
            val res=response
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val retro:List<DataCart> = response.body()!!.data
      totalamount.setText(response.body()?.total.toString())

                generateDataList(retro as MutableList<DataCart?>)

            }
        }

    })
}
fun generateDataList( dataList:MutableList<DataCart?>) {
    val recyclerView=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.addtocartrecyleview) as? RecyclerView
    val linear:LinearLayoutManager=
        LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager=linear
    val adapter = CartAdapter(this@AddToCart,dataList)
    recyclerView?.adapter=adapter
    recyclerView?.addItemDecoration
    (DividerItemDecorator(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)))
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    if (dataList.isEmpty()) {
        recyclerView?.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        textviewempty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    } else {
        recyclerView?.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        textviewempty.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    }




  recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(object :
        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            Log.e("RecyclerView", "onScrollStateChanged")
        }

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }
    })
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
}
```

}

i tried this-->by doing some changes-->

1--> **var dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>**

2--> **var dataList: MutableList<>?=null**

3--> **var dataList: MutableList<>**

Error log after doing Mutablelist to Arraylist

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.ArrayList<com.example.store.Cart.DataCart>
    at com.example.store.Cart.AddToCart$onCreate$1.onResponse(AddToCart.kt:40)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

but nothing seems to be handling null

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can be fixed by changing few lines:

Make CartAdapter accept nullable argument `dataList`, since your api request may return null and passing it would cause `NPE`.

```
class CartAdapter(context: Context, dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>?)
```

---

Since our `dataList` is nullable and calling `dataList.size` might throw `NPE` we need to make safe call using `?`. And if it's null we just return 0, telling `recyclerView` that there are 0 items.

```
override fun getItemCount() = datalist?.size ?: 0
```

---

Need to make `val retro:List<DataCart>` nullable, because `response.body()?.data` may return `null`. We just convert `retro` to mutableList using extension function `toMutableList()`, with safe call operator `"?"`. If `retro` is `null` then `null` value will be passed to `CartAdapter`, and since our adapter handles `null` value it will proceed without errors

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val retro:List<DataCart>? = response.body()?.data
                totalamount.setText(response.body()?.total.toString())
                generateDataList(retro?.toMutableList())
            }
```

---

**Remove** `init()` function from `CartAdapter`  and add `var`(actually should be `val`) before arguments in constructor. `init()` is redundant here because u r using it to assign values to redundant, duplicate member variables. By adding var(should be `val`)  to constructor arguments they will be assigned values and be available as member variables, right after object construction.

---

Since `dataList` is nullable, and we need to determine its size for further logic  safe call needs to be used, and if its `null` return `true`  - empty

```
 (dataList?.isEmpty() ?: true)
```

or use

```
`(dataList.isNullOrEmpty())`
```

which is cleaner, and should work too.

---

**NOTE:** Personally, i would'nt suggest you to retinitialize Adapter everytime you need to change values. Instead create val `items = arrayListOf<DataCart>().` as a member variable and add a setter function for updating it, inside of which you would call `notifyDatasetChanged()` or other notify methods.

Comment: app is crashing with     kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.MutableList<com.example.xx.Cart.DataCart?>  line indicating at --> `generateDataList(retro as MutableList<DataCart?>)`

Comment: can you remove init{} method completely? that seems kinda redundant, and see what happens?

Comment: if i remove that init {} ...it shows error at `private var dataList: MutableList<DataCart> private val context: Context` --> showing it must initialized

Comment: remove these two: private   var dataList: MutableList<DataCart>
private val context: Context.  And add "var" before arguments in constructor. This way you should be able to acces them withoud duplicating them as a global member variables. I can tell that you u r long time Java user :)

Comment: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException at line --> `if (dataList?.isEmpty()!!) {`

Comment: replace with if(dataList?.isEmpty() ?: true). Non null assertion "!!" is causing it

Comment: im accepting your answer ...giving you bounty...but i want you to edit your  answer with more explanation in it...like why is it causing null cast n all

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I will :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't find a reason to use `MutableList` but your issue is incorrect type cast `(dataList as MutableList<DataCart>)`. This is cause null cannot be cast to non-null type. You can simplify code using `class CartAdapter(private val context: Context, private val dataList: ArrayList<DataCart?>?)` and remove `var dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>`, `private val context: Context` and `init{}`

Comment: if i use list<> i wont be get access access to method `removeAt()` in code if you have seen in under  tvdelete onclicklistener....

Comment: @Wini i'm mean to use `ArrayList` not `MutableList`

Comment: @Wini post error log. `ArrayList<DataCart?>?` is nullable

Comment: posted my activity where im calling recycleview please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Null check by using the Elvis operator in the part to set in the shopping cart

The first or second method seems to be good